# MPI_TEST: invalid mpi_request

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I want to test if mpi_iSend and mpi_iRecv have run fine.

I have 2 request(argument) vectors: one vector for all the mpi_iSend, the other for all the mpi_iRecv.

The point is that the program runs fine until it started to run the cycle for MPI_TEST. I have tried even with 2 numbers (do i=1,2), still the same error.

> Fatal error in PMPI_Test: Invalid MPI_Request, error stack:
>   PMPI_Test(166): MPI_Test(request=0x7fff93fd2220, flag=0x7fff93fd1ffc,
>   status=0x7fff93fd2890) failed PMPI_Test(121): Invalid MPI_Request

```
INTEGER :: ierr, myid, istatus(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), num, i, n
INTEGER,parameter :: seed = 86456, numbers=200 
INTEGER :: req1(numbers), req2(numbers)
LOGICAL :: flag

CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
IF (myid==0) THEN

    DO n=1, numbers

        req1(n)=0
        req2(n)=0
        num=IRAND()

        CALL MPI_ISEND(num,1,MPI_INTEGER,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req1(n),ierr)
        CALL MPI_IRECV(best_prime,1,MPI_INTEGER,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req2(n),ierr)

    END DO

ELSE IF (myid==1) THEN

    DO i=1, numbers
        CALL MPI_TEST(req2(i),flag,istatus,ierr)
        IF (flag .eqv. .false.) THEN
            WRITE(*,*)'RECV',i,'non-blocking FAIL'
        ELSE IF (flag .eqv. .true.) THEN
            WRITE(*,*)'RECV',i,'non-blocking SUCCESS'
        END IF
    END DO

END IF
```

Comment: How is `istatus` declared?

Comment: ok, updated it with var declarations

Comment: Do you have matching sends and receives? Right now, it appears that you are only on the slave nodes in a Master/Slave paradigm because you are sending/receiving to node 1. Does node 1 have a matching send/recv?

Comment: yeah, i've updated it.